# Кеширование в laravel запросов к БД

Tags: php, база-данных, laravel

Нужен совет, возможно решить мою проблему кешированием или как то по другому.

Есть самодельная Learning Management System очень скудного функционала под 200-300 пользователей.

Но вот проблема, чтобы в топбаре показать уведомления, непрочитанные внутренние сообщения, прогресс обучения и онлайн обучающихся, я загнал все это в ViewComposer и в результате получилось 90 запросов к бд при каждом запросе страниц.

Вот вывод из debugbar bit.ly/32JR86a.

Как решаются такие вопросы? Ведь вывод всей этой информации — типовая задача для многих проектов, а я велосипед изобретаю с квадратными колесами.
Вот класс компосера:

```
    class ShareComposer
{
    protected $user;
    protected $profile;
    protected $notifications;
    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->user = Auth::user();

        if ($this->user != null) {
            $this->notifications = $this->user->unreadNotifications;
        }
    }
    public function compose(View $view)
    {
        if ($this->user != null) {
            $roles = $this->user->getRoleNames();
            $unreadMessagesCount = $this->user->unreadMessagesCount();
            $unreadThreads = Thread::forUserWithNewMessages(Auth::id())->latest('updated_at')->get();
            if ($roles->contains('administrator')) {
                $homeworksResultsCount = HomeWorkResult::where('accepted', 0)->where('checked', 0)->count();
                $guestsCount = Guest::where('accepted', 0)->where('checked', 0)->count();
                $view->with([
                    'user' => $this->user,
                    'notifications' => $this->notifications,
                    'unreadMessagesCount' => $unreadMessagesCount,
                    'homeworkResultsCount' => $homeworksResultsCount,
                    'guestsCount' => $guestsCount,
                    'unreadThreads' => $unreadThreads
                ]);
            }

            if ($roles->contains('student')) {
                $current_lesson = User::find($this->user->id)->lessons()->orderBy('position', 'desc')->first();
                $current_lesson_id = $current_lesson->id;
                $time_to_learn = $current_lesson->time_to_learn;
                $lesson_student = DB::table('lesson_student')->where('user_id', $this->user->id)->where('lesson_id', $current_lesson_id)->get();
                $start_time = Carbon::parse($lesson_student->pluck('created_at')[0]);
                $end_time = $start_time->addDays($time_to_learn);
                $date_now = Carbon::today();
                $remain_days = $end_time->diffInDays($date_now);
                $view->with([
                    'user' => $this->user,
                    'notifications' => $this->notifications,
                    'unreadMessagesCount' => $unreadMessagesCount,
                    'remain_days' => $remain_days,
                    'unreadThreads' => $unreadThreads
                ]);
            }

            if ($roles->contains('user')) {
                $view->with([
                    'user' => $this->user,
                    'notifications' => $this->notifications,
                    'unreadMessagesCount' => $unreadMessagesCount,
                    'unreadThreads' => $unreadThreads
                ]);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: **select * from `users` where `users`.`id` = 3** - это я так понимаю, что вы подгружаете данные о текущем зарегистрированном пользователе?

Comment: да, добавил класс компосера в текст вопроса, что бы было понятно какие запросы формируются

Comment: нынче выбирать только нужные поля в запросе не модно стало что ли?

Comment: Выносить нужно всю эту логику в отдельный класс (сервис) и через геттеры забирать необходимую информацию, которая бы создавалась единожды. Исключать также подобные запросы `User::find($this->user->id)`. Избегать подобного `DB::table('lesson_student')`. Кэширование не панацея.

Comment: В данном случае надо не кэшировать а разбираться с запросами. По описанному сценарию там не должно быть 90 запросов, а в 10 раз меньше. Надо смотреть что там запросы рисует Елоквент, и либо переделывать, либо писать руками.

Сама идея кэширования уведомлений звучит по-дурацки. Уведомление - это то что мы хотим видеть сразу, а не когда кэш протухнет.

Вообще надо запомнить простое правило - кэширование создаёт очень много проблем и прибегать к нему стоит только в самом крайнем случае, когда все остальные средства уже исчерпаны.

Answer (score 0):

Вижу, что вопрос был задач более 4 лет назад.
Тем не менее отвечу, чтобы другие пользователи смогли понять причину, если возникнет аналогичная ситуация.

Взглянул на список запросов.
Очень вероятно, что причина в следующем.

Был создан файл ShareComposer, который собирает необходимые данные с помощью запросов к MySQL.
Причина большого кол-ва запросов к MySQL не в самом этом файле ShareComposer, а в том, что в провайдере ViewServiceProvider установлены "неверные" настройки. К примеру, данные из этого ShareComposer передаются не в один конкретный шаблон, а в несколько шаблонов. Ну, например, так:

```
public function boot()
{
        //  Для ВСЕХ шаблонов
        View::composer('*', 'App\ViewComposers\ShareComposer');
}
```

Это означает, что метод compose данного класса ShareComposer будет вызываться  для каждого шаблона View, который используется для генерации страницы.

## Решения

Решение №1. В некоторых случаях нужно просто установить один шаблон, в котором используются данные из класса ShareComposer

Решение №2. Выполнять проверку на наличие подгруженных ранее данных. Примерно так

```
if(empty( $view->getData()['notifications'] )) {
 # возвращаем счетчик уведомлений
}
```

Решение №3. Сохранять данные в кэш только для текущего запроса. В документации к Laravel описан этот способ. Таким образом, если повторно запрашиваются данные для того же HTTP-запроса, то они вызываются из кэша (который хранится в памяти, а не на диске). После завершения HTTP-запроса кэш памяти очищается самостоятельно, поэтому не нужно заботиться о "испорченом" кэше.