# Laravel & debugbar дубликаты запросов к БД

Tags: база-данных, laravel, отладка

Для отображения в меню уведомлений (сообщения, события и т.п.) я загнал логику в  ViewComposer и в результате Laravel dubugbar показывает 68 запросов к бд при обращении к станицам. Хотел кешировать эти запросы и [спрашивал](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1045922/%D0%9A%D0%B5%D1%88%D0%B8%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5-%D0%B2-laravel-%D0%B7%D0%B0%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D1%81%D0%BE%D0%B2-%D0%BA-%D0%91%D0%94) какие вообще подходы существуют к решению этой проблемы. Но при внимательном рассмотрении лога обнаружил, что это просто дубликаты, об этом и сообщает и сам dubugbar в заголовке лога:

```
63 statements were executed, 58 of which were duplicated, 5 unique
```

Внизу полный log из debugbar.

**Вопрос**: каким образом сформировались *дубликаты* обращений к БД? Возможно это баг самого debugbar?

Вот класс Composer:

```
    class ShareComposer
{
    protected $user;
    protected $profile;
    protected $notifications;
    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->user = Auth::user();

        if ($this->user != null) {
            $this->notifications = $this->user->unreadNotifications;
        }
    }
    public function compose(View $view)
    {
        if ($this->user != null) {
            $roles = $this->user->getRoleNames();
            $unreadMessagesCount = $this->user->unreadMessagesCount();
            $unreadThreads = Thread::forUserWithNewMessages(Auth::id())->latest('updated_at')->get();
            if ($roles->contains('administrator')) {
                $homeworksResultsCount = HomeWorkResult::where('accepted', 0)->where('checked', 0)->count();
                $guestsCount = Guest::where('accepted', 0)->where('checked', 0)->count();
                $view->with([
                    'user' => $this->user,
                    'notifications' => $this->notifications,
                    'unreadMessagesCount' => $unreadMessagesCount,
                    'homeworkResultsCount' => $homeworksResultsCount,
                    'guestsCount' => $guestsCount,
                    'unreadThreads' => $unreadThreads
                ]);
            }

            if ($roles->contains('student')) {
                $current_lesson = User::find($this->user->id)->lessons()->orderBy('position', 'desc')->first();
                $current_lesson_id = $current_lesson->id;
                $time_to_learn = $current_lesson->time_to_learn;
                $lesson_student = DB::table('lesson_student')->where('user_id', $this->user->id)->where('lesson_id', $current_lesson_id)->get();
                $start_time = Carbon::parse($lesson_student->pluck('created_at')[0]);
                $end_time = $start_time->addDays($time_to_learn);
                $date_now = Carbon::today();
                $remain_days = $end_time->diffInDays($date_now);
                $view->with([
                    'user' => $this->user,
                    'notifications' => $this->notifications,
                    'unreadMessagesCount' => $unreadMessagesCount,
                    'remain_days' => $remain_days,
                    'unreadThreads' => $unreadThreads
                ]);
            }

            if ($roles->contains('user')) {
                $view->with([
                    'user' => $this->user,
                    'notifications' => $this->notifications,
                    'unreadMessagesCount' => $unreadMessagesCount,
                    'unreadThreads' => $unreadThreads
                ]);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**log** из debugbar:

```
select * from `sessions` where `id` = 'ELWPR27bZEICgtHWwGeVYA5msJQlTuSywq66evKe' limit 1
2.7ms
/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Session/DatabaseSessionHandler.php:91
admin_school
select * from `users` where `id` = 1 limit 1
810μs
/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Auth/EloquentUserProvider.php:52
admin_school
select `roles`.*, `model_has_roles`.`model_id` as `pivot_model_id`, `model_has_roles`.`role_id` as `pivot_role_id`, `model_has_roles`.`model_type` as `pivot_model_type` from `roles` inner join `model_has_roles` on `roles`.`id` = `model_has_roles`.`role_id` where `model_has_roles`.`model_id` = 1 and `model_has_roles`.`model_type` = 'App\User'
430μs
/vendor/spatie/laravel-permission/src/Traits/HasRoles.php:188
admin_school
select * from `notifications` where `notifications`.`notifiable_id` = 1 and `notifications`.`notifiable_id` is not null and `notifications`.`notifiable_type` = 'App\User' and `read_at` is null order by `created_at` desc
2.85ms
/app/Http/ViewComposers/ShareComposer.php:30
admin_school
select count(*) as aggregate from `messages` where exists (select * from `threads` where `messages`.`thread_id` = `threads`.`id` and `threads`.`deleted_at` is null) and `user_id` != 1 and exists (select * from `participants` where `messages`.`thread_id` = `participants`.`thread_id` and `user_id` = 1 and (`last_read` < messages.created_at or `last_read` is null) and `participants`.`deleted_at` is null) and `messages`.`deleted_at` is null
400μs
/app/Http/Controllers/Traits/Messagable.php:71
admin_school
select `threads`.* from `threads` inner join `participants` on `threads`.`id` = `participants`.`thread_id` where `participants`.`user_id` = 1 and `participants`.`deleted_at` is null and (`threads`.`updated_at` > participants.last_read or `participants`.`last_read` is null) and `threads`.`deleted_at` is null order by `updated_at` desc
320μs
/app/Http/ViewComposers/ShareComposer.php:39
admin_school
select count(*) as aggregate from `homework_result` where `accepted` = 0 and `checked` = 0
270μs
/app/Http/ViewComposers/ShareComposer.php:42
admin_school
select count(*) as aggregate from `guests` where `accepted` = 0 and `checked` = 0
350μs
/app/Http/ViewComposers/ShareComposer.php:43
admin_school
select count(*) as aggregate from `messages` where exists (select * from `threads` where `messages`.`thread_id` = `threads`.`id` and `threads`.`deleted_at` is null) and `user_id` != 1 and exists (select * from `participants` where `messages`.`thread_id` = `participants`.`thread_id` and `user_id` = 1 and (`last_read` < messages.created_at or `last_read` is null) and `participants`.`deleted_at` is null) and `messages`.`deleted_at` is null
440μs
/app/Http/Controllers/Traits/Messagable.php:71
admin_school
select `threads`.* from `threads` inner join `participants` on `threads`.`id` = `participants`.`thread_id` where `participants`.`user_id` = 1 and `participants`.`deleted_at` is null and (`threads`.`updated_at` > participants.last_read or `participants`.`last_read` is null) and `threads`.`deleted_at` is null order by `updated_at` desc
380μs
/app/Http/ViewComposers/ShareComposer.php:39
admin_school
select count(*) as aggregate from `homework_result` where `accepted` = 0 and `checked` = 0
260μs
/app/Http/ViewComposers/ShareComposer.php:42
admin_school
select count(*) as aggregate from `guests` where `accepted` = 0 and `checked` = 0
350μs
/app/Http/ViewComposers/ShareComposer.php:43
admin_school
select count(*) as aggregate from `messages` where exists (select * from `threads` where `messages`.`thread_id` = `threads`.`id` and `threads`.`deleted_at` is null) and `user_id` != 1 and exists (select * from `participants` where `messages`.`thread_id` = `participants`.`thread_id` and `user_id` = 1 and (`last_read` < messages.created_at or `last_read` is null) and `participants`.`deleted_at` is null) and `messages`.`deleted_at` is null
6.07ms
/app/Http/Controllers/Traits/Messagable.php:71
admin_school
select `threads`.* from `threads` inner join `participants` on `threads`.`id` = `participants`.`thread_id` where `participants`.`user_id` = 1 and `participants`.`deleted_at` is null and (`threads`.`updated_at` > participants.last_read or `participants`.`last_read` is null) and `threads`.`deleted_at` is null order by `updated_at` desc
2.33ms
/app/Http/ViewComposers/ShareComposer.php:39
admin_school
select count(*) as aggregate from `homework_result` where `accepted` = 0 and `checked` = 0
2.19ms
/app/Http/ViewComposers/ShareComposer.php:42
admin_school
select count(*) as aggregate from `guests` where `accepted` = 0 and `checked` = 0
2.08ms
/app/Http/ViewComposers/ShareComposer.php:43
admin_school
select count(*) as aggregate from `messages` where exists (select * from `threads` where `messages`.`thread_id` = `threads`.`id` and `threads`.`deleted_at` is null) and `user_id` != 1 and exists (select * from `participants` where `messages`.`thread_id` = `participants`.`thread_id` and `user_id` = 1 and (`last_read` < messages.created_at or `last_read` is null) and `participants`.`deleted_at` is null) and `messages`.`deleted_at` is null
4.06ms
/app/Http/Controllers/Traits/Messagable.php:71
admin_school
select `threads`.* from `threads` inner join `participants` on `threads`.`id` = `participants`.`thread_id` where `participants`.`user_id` = 1 and `participants`.`deleted_at` is null and (`threads`.`updated_at` > participants.last_read or `participants`.`last_read` is null) and `threads`.`deleted_at` is null order by `updated_at` desc
2.27ms
/app/Http/ViewComposers/ShareComposer.php:39
admin_school
select count(*) as aggregate from `homework_result` where `accepted` = 0 and `checked` = 0
2.18ms
/app/Http/ViewComposers/ShareComposer.php:42
admin_school
select count(*) as aggregate from `guests` where `accepted` = 0 and `checked` = 0
2.29ms
/app/Http/ViewComposers/ShareComposer.php:43
admin_school
select count(*) as aggregate from `messages` where exists (select * from `threads` where `messages`.`thread_id` = `threads`.`id` and `threads`.`deleted_at` is null) and `user_id` != 1 and exists (select * from `participants` where `messages`.`thread_id` = `participants`.`thread_id` and `user_id` = 1 and (`last_read` < messages.created_at or `last_read` is null) and `participants`.`deleted_at` is null) and `messages`.`deleted_at` is null
4.75ms
/app/Http/Controllers/Traits/Messagable.php:71
admin_school
select `threads`.* from `threads` inner join `participants` on `threads`.`id` = `participants`.`thread_id` where `participants`.`user_id` = 1 and `participants`.`deleted_at` is null and (`threads`.`updated_at` > participants.last_read or `participants`.`last_read` is null) and `threads`.`deleted_at` is null order by `updated_at` desc
2.3ms
/app/Http/ViewComposers/ShareComposer.php:39
admin_school
select count(*) as aggregate from `homework_result` where `accepted` = 0 and `checked` = 0
2.94ms
/app/Http/ViewComposers/ShareComposer.php:42
admin_school
select count(*) as aggregate from `guests` where `accepted` = 0 and `checked` = 0
3.84ms
/app/Http/ViewComposers/ShareComposer.php:43
admin_school
select count(*) as aggregate from `messages` where exists (select * from `threads` where `messages`.`thread_id` = `threads`.`id` and `threads`.`deleted_at` is null) and `user_id` != 1 and exists (select * from `participants` where `messages`.`thread_id` = `participants`.`thread_id` and `user_id` = 1 and (`last_read` < messages.created_at or `last_read` is null) and `participants`.`deleted_at` is null) and `messages`.`deleted_at` is null
4.41ms
/app/Http/Controllers/Traits/Messagable.php:71
admin_school
select `threads`.* from `threads` inner join `participants` on `threads`.`id` = `participants`.`thread_id` where `participants`.`user_id` = 1 and `participants`.`deleted_at` is null and (`threads`.`updated_at` > participants.last_read or `participants`.`last_read` is null) and `threads`.`deleted_at` is null order by `updated_at` desc
2.42ms
/app/Http/ViewComposers/ShareComposer.php:39
admin_school
select count(*) as aggregate from `homework_result` where `accepted` = 0 and `checked` = 0
2.19ms
/app/Http/ViewComposers/ShareComposer.php:42
admin_school
select count(*) as aggregate from `guests` where `accepted` = 0 and `checked` = 0
2.22ms
/app/Http/ViewComposers/ShareComposer.php:43
admin_school
select count(*) as aggregate from `messages` where exists (select * from `threads` where `messages`.`thread_id` = `threads`.`id` and `threads`.`deleted_at` is null) and `user_id` != 1 and exists (select * from `participants` where `messages`.`thread_id` = `participants`.`thread_id` and `user_id` = 1 and (`last_read` < messages.created_at or `last_read` is null) and `participants`.`deleted_at` is null) and `messages`.`deleted_at` is null
4.07ms
/app/Http/Controllers/Traits/Messagable.php:71
admin_school
select `threads`.* from `threads` inner join `participants` on `threads`.`id` = `participants`.`thread_id` where `participants`.`user_id` = 1 and `participants`.`deleted_at` is null and (`threads`.`updated_at` > participants.last_read or `participants`.`last_read` is null) and `threads`.`deleted_at` is null order by `updated_at` desc
2.12ms
/app/Http/ViewComposers/ShareComposer.php:39
admin_school
select count(*) as aggregate from `homework_result` where `accepted` = 0 and `checked` = 0
2.25ms
/app/Http/ViewComposers/ShareComposer.php:42
admin_school
select count(*) as aggregate from `guests` where `accepted` = 0 and `checked` = 0
570μs
/app/Http/ViewComposers/ShareComposer.php:43
admin_school
select count(*) as aggregate from `messages` where exists (select * from `threads` where `messages`.`thread_id` = `threads`.`id` and `threads`.`deleted_at` is null) and `user_id` != 1 and exists (select * from `participants` where `messages`.`thread_id` = `participants`.`thread_id` and `user_id` = 1 and (`last_read` < messages.created_at or `last_read` is null) and `participants`.`deleted_at` is null) and `messages`.`deleted_at` is null
3.8ms
/app/Http/Controllers/Traits/Messagable.php:71
admin_school
select `threads`.* from `threads` inner join `participants` on `threads`.`id` = `participants`.`thread_id` where `participants`.`user_id` = 1 and `participants`.`deleted_at` is null and (`threads`.`updated_at` > participants.last_read or `participants`.`last_read` is null) and `threads`.`deleted_at` is null order by `updated_at` desc
3.88ms
/app/Http/ViewComposers/ShareComposer.php:39
admin_school
select count(*) as aggregate from `homework_result` where `accepted` = 0 and `checked` = 0
540μs
/app/Http/ViewComposers/ShareComposer.php:42
admin_school
select count(*) as aggregate from `guests` where `accepted` = 0 and `checked` = 0
2.41ms
/app/Http/ViewComposers/ShareComposer.php:43
admin_school
select count(*) as aggregate from `messages` where exists (select * from `threads` where `messages`.`thread_id` = `threads`.`id` and `threads`.`deleted_at` is null) and `user_id` != 1 and exists (select * from `participants` where `messages`.`thread_id` = `participants`.`thread_id` and `user_id` = 1 and (`last_read` < messages.created_at or `last_read` is null) and `participants`.`deleted_at` is null) and `messages`.`deleted_at` is null
3.69ms
/app/Http/Controllers/Traits/Messagable.php:71
admin_school
select `threads`.* from `threads` inner join `participants` on `threads`.`id` = `participants`.`thread_id` where `participants`.`user_id` = 1 and `participants`.`deleted_at` is null and (`threads`.`updated_at` > participants.last_read or `participants`.`last_read` is null) and `threads`.`deleted_at` is null order by `updated_at` desc
8.94ms
/app/Http/ViewComposers/ShareComposer.php:39
admin_school
select count(*) as aggregate from `homework_result` where `accepted` = 0 and `checked` = 0
460μs
/app/Http/ViewComposers/ShareComposer.php:42
admin_school
select count(*) as aggregate from `guests` where `accepted` = 0 and `checked` = 0
440μs
/app/Http/ViewComposers/ShareComposer.php:43
admin_school
select count(*) as aggregate from `messages` where exists (select * from `threads` where `messages`.`thread_id` = `threads`.`id` and `threads`.`deleted_at` is null) and `user_id` != 1 and exists (select * from `participants` where `messages`.`thread_id` = `participants`.`thread_id` and `user_id` = 1 and (`last_read` < messages.created_at or `last_read` is null) and `participants`.`deleted_at` is null) and `messages`.`deleted_at` is null
3.92ms
/app/Http/Controllers/Traits/Messagable.php:71
admin_school
select `threads`.* from `threads` inner join `participants` on `threads`.`id` = `participants`.`thread_id` where `participants`.`user_id` = 1 and `participants`.`deleted_at` is null and (`threads`.`updated_at` > participants.last_read or `participants`.`last_read` is null) and `threads`.`deleted_at` is null order by `updated_at` desc
3.81ms
/app/Http/ViewComposers/ShareComposer.php:39
admin_school
select count(*) as aggregate from `homework_result` where `accepted` = 0 and `checked` = 0
520μs
/app/Http/ViewComposers/ShareComposer.php:42
admin_school
select count(*) as aggregate from `guests` where `accepted` = 0 and `checked` = 0
1.97ms
/app/Http/ViewComposers/ShareComposer.php:43
admin_school
select `permissions`.*, `model_has_permissions`.`model_id` as `pivot_model_id`, `model_has_permissions`.`permission_id` as `pivot_permission_id`, `model_has_permissions`.`model_type` as `pivot_model_type` from `permissions` inner join `model_has_permissions` on `permissions`.`id` = `model_has_permissions`.`permission_id` where `model_has_permissions`.`model_id` = 1 and `model_has_permissions`.`model_type` = 'App\User'
5.35ms
/vendor/spatie/laravel-permission/src/Traits/HasPermissions.php:258
admin_school
select count(*) as aggregate from `messages` where exists (select * from `threads` where `messages`.`thread_id` = `threads`.`id` and `threads`.`deleted_at` is null) and `user_id` != 1 and exists (select * from `participants` where `messages`.`thread_id` = `participants`.`thread_id` and `user_id` = 1 and (`last_read` < messages.created_at or `last_read` is null) and `participants`.`deleted_at` is null) and `messages`.`deleted_at` is null
5.09ms
/app/Http/Controllers/Traits/Messagable.php:71
admin_school
select `threads`.* from `threads` inner join `participants` on `threads`.`id` = `participants`.`thread_id` where `participants`.`user_id` = 1 and `participants`.`deleted_at` is null and (`threads`.`updated_at` > participants.last_read or `participants`.`last_read` is null) and `threads`.`deleted_at` is null order by `updated_at` desc
4.37ms
/app/Http/ViewComposers/ShareComposer.php:39
admin_school
select count(*) as aggregate from `homework_result` where `accepted` = 0 and `checked` = 0
3.33ms
/app/Http/ViewComposers/ShareComposer.php:42
admin_school
select count(*) as aggregate from `guests` where `accepted` = 0 and `checked` = 0
2.06ms
/app/Http/ViewComposers/ShareComposer.php:43
admin_school
select count(*) as aggregate from `messages` where exists (select * from `threads` where `messages`.`thread_id` = `threads`.`id` and `threads`.`deleted_at` is null) and `user_id` != 1 and exists (select * from `participants` where `messages`.`thread_id` = `participants`.`thread_id` and `user_id` = 1 and (`last_read` < messages.created_at or `last_read` is null) and `participants`.`deleted_at` is null) and `messages`.`deleted_at` is null
3.68ms
/app/Http/Controllers/Traits/Messagable.php:71
admin_school
select `threads`.* from `threads` inner join `participants` on `threads`.`id` = `participants`.`thread_id` where `participants`.`user_id` = 1 and `participants`.`deleted_at` is null and (`threads`.`updated_at` > participants.last_read or `participants`.`last_read` is null) and `threads`.`deleted_at` is null order by `updated_at` desc
2.24ms
/app/Http/ViewComposers/ShareComposer.php:39
admin_school
select count(*) as aggregate from `homework_result` where `accepted` = 0 and `checked` = 0
2ms
/app/Http/ViewComposers/ShareComposer.php:42
admin_school
select count(*) as aggregate from `guests` where `accepted` = 0 and `checked` = 0
1.87ms
/app/Http/ViewComposers/ShareComposer.php:43
admin_school
select count(*) as aggregate from `messages` where exists (select * from `threads` where `messages`.`thread_id` = `threads`.`id` and `threads`.`deleted_at` is null) and `user_id` != 1 and exists (select * from `participants` where `messages`.`thread_id` = `participants`.`thread_id` and `user_id` = 1 and (`last_read` < messages.created_at or `last_read` is null) and `participants`.`deleted_at` is null) and `messages`.`deleted_at` is null
4.05ms
/app/Http/Controllers/Traits/Messagable.php:71
admin_school
select `threads`.* from `threads` inner join `participants` on `threads`.`id` = `participants`.`thread_id` where `participants`.`user_id` = 1 and `participants`.`deleted_at` is null and (`threads`.`updated_at` > participants.last_read or `participants`.`last_read` is null) and `threads`.`deleted_at` is null order by `updated_at` desc
2.18ms
/app/Http/ViewComposers/ShareComposer.php:39
admin_school
select count(*) as aggregate from `homework_result` where `accepted` = 0 and `checked` = 0
2.07ms
/app/Http/ViewComposers/ShareComposer.php:42
admin_school
select count(*) as aggregate from `guests` where `accepted` = 0 and `checked` = 0
2.27ms
/app/Http/ViewComposers/ShareComposer.php:43
admin_school
select count(*) as aggregate from `messages` where exists (select * from `threads` where `messages`.`thread_id` = `threads`.`id` and `threads`.`deleted_at` is null) and `user_id` != 1 and exists (select * from `participants` where `messages`.`thread_id` = `participants`.`thread_id` and `user_id` = 1 and (`last_read` < messages.created_at or `last_read` is null) and `participants`.`deleted_at` is null) and `messages`.`deleted_at` is null
3.97ms
/app/Http/Controllers/Traits/Messagable.php:71
admin_school
select `threads`.* from `threads` inner join `participants` on `threads`.`id` = `participants`.`thread_id` where `participants`.`user_id` = 1 and `participants`.`deleted_at` is null and (`threads`.`updated_at` > participants.last_read or `participants`.`last_read` is null) and `threads`.`deleted_at` is null order by `updated_at` desc
2.06ms
/app/Http/ViewComposers/ShareComposer.php:39
admin_school
select count(*) as aggregate from `homework_result` where `accepted` = 0 and `checked` = 0
2.03ms
/app/Http/ViewComposers/ShareComposer.php:42
admin_school
select count(*) as aggregate from `guests` where `accepted` = 0 and `checked` = 0
2.46ms
/app/Http/ViewComposers/ShareComposer.php:43
admin_school
update `sessions` set `payload` = 'YTo1OntzOjY6Il90b2tlbiI7czo0MDoiQ1A4QlNtUFNKZ0RGakxtMWNRMFRHTWRWd2E0R1dEbWMyeVk5clVyTiI7czo5OiJfcHJldmlvdXMiO2E6MTp7czozOiJ1cmwiO3M6MzA6Imh0dHA6Ly9zY2hvb2wubG9jYWwvYWRtaW4vaG9tZSI7fXM6NjoiX2ZsYXNoIjthOjI6e3M6Mzoib2xkIjthOjA6e31zOjM6Im5ldyI7YTowOnt9fXM6MzoidXJsIjthOjA6e31zOjUwOiJsb2dpbl93ZWJfNTliYTM2YWRkYzJiMmY5NDAxNTgwZjAxNGM3ZjU4ZWE0ZTMwOTg5ZCI7aToxO30=', `last_activity` = 1574006874, `user_id` = 1, `ip_address` = '192.168.10.1', `user_agent` = 'Mozilla/5.0 (Linux; Android 8.0.0; Nexus 5X Build/OPR4.170623.006) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/78.0.3904.70 Mobile Safari/537.36' where `id` = 'ELWPR27bZEICgtHWwGeVYA5msJQlTuSywq66evKe'
3.47ms
/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Session/DatabaseSessionHandler.php:165
admin_school
select * from `sessions` where `id` = 'ELWPR27bZEICgtHWwGeVYA5msJQlTuSywq66evKe' limit 1
3.96ms
/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Session/DatabaseSessionHandler.php:91
admin_school
```

Comment: `каким образом сформировались дубликаты обращений к БД` - метод `compose` класса вызывается каждый раз при рендеринге каждого из представлений. `Возможно это баг самого debugbar` - нет, это не баг, это логирование запросов приложения

Comment: Можешь объявить во ViewComposer'е свойства и заносить туда результаты обращений к БД. При следующем обращении к этому ViewComposer'у бери результат уже из свойств класса

Comment: Это скорей всего проблемы с выводом данных. Мне кажется вы где то в цикле используете связи и поэтому получаете много запросов. Проверьте view для начала.